# How to get the shipping rates via AJAX?

Tags: magento2, cart, javascript, ajax

When I update the product qty in the cart page I want to have the shipping rates estimated again via AJAX, how could I call this JS method in order to do that?

[image: Magento2 ajax cart update shipping rates]